# Apply sum distrutively to tuples

Tags: python, sum, tuples

I'd like to have an algorithm which calculates the transitions from these STATE/ACTIONS tuples. For example, if you are in state (2,1) you can transition to states [(2,2),(2,0)]. This is calculated by adding the actions [(0,1),(-1,0)], to the state (2,1). I'm somewhat new to python so I'm wondering what the most efficient way to do this is. I would end up with a dict similar to the ACTIONS dict. Thanks!!

```
STATES=[
(0,0),
(0,1),
(0,2),
(0,3),
(1,0),
# '1,1',
(1,2),
(1,3),
(2,0),
(2,1),
(2,2),
(2,3)
]

ACTIONS={
(0,0):[(0,1),(1,0)],
(0,1):[(0,1),(0,-1)],
(0,2):[(0,-1),(1,0),(0,1)],
(0,3):[(0,-1),(1,0)],
(1,0):[(1,0),(-1,0)],
# '1,1':0,
(1,2):[(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1)],
(1,3):[],
(2,0):[(0,1),(-1,0)],
(2,1):[(0,1),(0,-1)],
(2,2):[(0,-1),(-1,0),(0,1)],
(2,3):[]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a list of possible offsets corresponding to the actions available. From there, you build a dictionary of actions using the state as key.

```
STATES=[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]

offsets = [(0, 1),(-1, 0), (1, 1), (-1, -1)]

actions = {}
for state in STATES:
    actions[state] = [(state[0] + off0, state[1] + off1) for off0, off1 in offsets]

actions
```

#### output:

```
{(0, 0): [(0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 1), (-1, -1)],
 (0, 1): [(0, 2), (-1, 1), (1, 2), (-1, 0)],
 (0, 2): [(0, 3), (-1, 2), (1, 3), (-1, 1)],
 (0, 3): [(0, 4), (-1, 3), (1, 4), (-1, 2)],
 (1, 0): [(1, 1), (0, 0), (2, 1), (0, -1)],
 (1, 2): [(1, 3), (0, 2), (2, 3), (0, 1)],
 (1, 3): [(1, 4), (0, 3), (2, 4), (0, 2)],
 (2, 0): [(2, 1), (1, 0), (3, 1), (1, -1)],
 (2, 1): [(2, 2), (1, 1), (3, 2), (1, 0)],
 (2, 2): [(2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 3), (1, 1)],
 (2, 3): [(2, 4), (1, 3), (3, 4), (1, 2)]}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for although I would use the actions from above I would loop through actions to get the output. I know how to use that notation actually but somehow it escaped me that I could use state inside the brackets...